# strstr not functioning

Tags: c, input, fgets, strstr

Why does this particular piece of code return false on the strstr() if I input "test"?

```
char input[100];

int main()
{
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    printf("%s", input);

    if(strstr("test message", input))
    {
        printf("strstr true");

    }


}
```

I thought strstr searched the first param for instances of the second param? It works when I replace input with some text or just assign it something directly, but it seems to not work with fgets.

Comment: As for dealing with the problem, there's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because fgets stores the newline character so when strstr does a comparison it fails.

From the man page:

> fgets()  reads  in  at most one less than size characters from stream
>   and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after
>   an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored
>          into the buffer.  A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Comment: Remove the probably and you get +1 :)

Comment: @sashang that document part is still confusing. It says EOF or newline. Which is it? I was going through a tutorial and it was failing me. Replacing the last character with a null `\0` did the trick but the tutorial made it seem like `fgets` automatically puts `\0` when in fact it puts `\n`. Because of this `strstr` was not functioning. But then why did the book say it would work?

Comment: @Andy: 'EOF or newline' means either EOF or newline or both of them. 'or' here has the meaning of the logical boolean or and not 'or' that is used in colloquial English. Therefore both of them is a valid answer.

Answer (score 7):

Add `input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';` after the `fgets`. `fgets` reads in the newline char (`'\n'`). There is no `'\n'` in `"test message"` so `input` will never be contained within it.

You should really check to see if the newline is at the end of the buffer after calling `fgets` to know if the whole line was able to actually fit into it, and also to obviously remove it.

Comment: am I to assume that when `fgets` reads, say, `"Hello"`, it actually reads `"Hello\n\0"` or `"Hello\n"`.

Comment: It reads `"Hello\n"` and then terminates the string with a `'\0'`. But that's only if there's a newline character to be read.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. What should the total result be of `fget`? I ask because `strstr` isn't working. When i do `variable[strlen(variable)-1] = '\0'`, it works. When `strlen` parses the string for the length, does it skip the terminating null value? So `"Hello\n\0"`, is it 6 because it includes the newline? And if so, then the result would be `"Hello\0\0"` if thats how I would solve my problem which is a bit wasteful. Thanks for your time by the way.

Comment: `strlen` counts *every* character *up until* a `'\0'`. So, yes, it includes the `'\n'`.

Comment: Addendum: If fgets() is reading from a text file, it will read `"Hello\n"` if your encoding uses `LF` for new line but if your encoding uses `CRLF` for new line it will read `"Hello\r\n"` N.B. `LF` means Line Feed (cursor drops to next line but remains in same column) and `CR` means Carriage Return (cursor moves to beginning of line)